# Unable to display string from snapshot

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to get data from firestore and display in the text but an eror has popup.
Thar error say type '_BroadcsastStream' is not a subtype of type 'String'.
Class i call the method

```
void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
  home : profUser(),
));

class profUser extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      home : new profiUser(),
    );
  }
}

class profiUser extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _profiUserState createState() => _profiUserState();
}

class _profiUserState extends State<profiUser> {    
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.indigo,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Profile'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(choices[1].icon),
            onPressed: (){
              logOut();
              Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)
              => myLogin()));
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),

      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          userDetail(),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Class to display text based on the data from firestore

```
class userDetail extends StatelessWidget{
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return new StreamBuilder(
        stream: UniQuery().getUserDetail(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot){
          if(!snapshot.hasData)
            return new Text('Loading..... Please wait');

          var userDocument = snapshot.data;
          return new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('Name: ' + userDocument['name']),
              Text('Age: ' + userDocument['age'],toString()),
              Text('Address: ' + userDocument['address']),
              Text('Result: ' + userDocument['result']),
            ],
          );
        }
    );
  }
}
```

Below the void that use in above code to get data from firestore

```
var userID;

      Future<String> getCurrentUser() async{
    final FirebaseUser user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
//    return uID != null ? uID : null;
    final String uID = user.uid.toString();
    return uID;
  }

  setUserDetail() async{
    userID = await getCurrentUser();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is inside getUserDetail() you are passing an async function to documents(), so that function returns a Future. Before calling documents() you should first get the string, waiting the async call to finish, and then pass the string to documents().

Comment: Did you change this on the other fields too? Name, Age, Address, Result?

Comment: yes i do on all of it.
i also try comment other fields and left only for name.
but still say type '_BroadcsastStream' is not a subtype of type 'String'.

Comment: In the console, did you check in which line of code is the error?

Comment: type '_BroadcastStream<QuerySnapshot>' is not a subtype of type 'String'
User-created ancestor of the error-causing widget was: 
  Column file:///D:/Compile/ttpproject/lib/profileUser.dart:45:13

Comment: Try reinstalling / restarting the app and not use hot reload.

Comment: i have found that cause of error..
i already edit on above code...
i mistaken call other function in getUserDetail()... now it ok but new error popup...
it say type 'Future<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Comment: i updated void use to get data from firestore and getcurrenUser..
but still it say type 'Future<String>' is not a subtype of type 'String'
i thought the value has be done after have future and aysnc with await

Comment: Because you are not waiting the getCurrentUser() async call to finish and you are getting a Future. Try this: userID = await getCurrentUser()